# Any reason why I can't use both the REST and SOAP versions of the DocuSign API together?

Tags: rest, soap, docusignapi

DocuSign highly recommends using the REST API instead of SOAP, and they push heavily for that in your initial implementation. They even suggest that new features may one day [only be implemented in REST](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/soap-api), which is my main concern. I'm leaning toward using their SOAP API anyway for our integration, and my primary question is this:

Let's assume the future scenario I fear - I build my DocuSign integration layer on the SOAP API. Next year, DocuSign does in fact leave the SOAP model behind, releases new features on the REST API only, and I desperately need to use one of those features. Is there any reason that I can't simply leave all of my SOAP integration in place, and implement integration with the new feature using the REST API? I understand that referencing both APIs would bloat the size of my deployment a bit, but I can accept that risk. Other than that, is there any compelling reason that I can't use both side-by-side? Would it break something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to use a mix of DocuSign SOAP API and REST API in your integration. In fact, that's a very common scenario for the exact reason you mention -- some features are implemented only in SOAP or only in REST, so it's often necessary to use a mixed approach in order to get the full functionality that you require.

Comment: Their documentation seems to be saying that to date, everything is implemented in both APIs. Can you point me to features that are only implemented in one or the other. If there is already a divergence in the feature set, I need to take those distinctions into consideration from the onset.

Comment: There are too many differences to enumerate here.  A couple of examples though -- the SOAP PurgeDocuments operation and the SOAP ExportAuthoritativeCopy operation currently have no REST API equivalents.  Instead of trying to compare/contrast the entire SOAP API vs the entire REST API, I'd suggest that you start with identifying which operations you'll need for your integration, and then determine 1x1 which of those operations exist in REST and which exist in SOAP. This will allow you to make the best decision for your particular case.

Comment: Appendix 1 of the REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) shows the SOAP API equivalent for each REST API method. (But do note -- this list only shows the UNION of the two APIs; it does NOT show any of differences.)